# JQuery and html code not working on local comp. (Codepen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this code in codepen.io  and it works as i want. But when i export/download the code to run locally on my computer it doesn't work.  It doesn't show the image and also doesn't alter the text like its supposed to. The downloaded index.html just shows the div text of 6,Background Image.

Html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="BackI" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;">6,Background Image</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
var text = $('.BackI').text().toLowerCase();
var str1 = text.split(',');

switch (str1[0]) {
  case '6':
    image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-grey-square-icons-symbols-shapes/120234-matte-grey-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
    break;
  case '99':
    image = 'http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/matte-red-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/124116-matte-red-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-tile.png';
    break;
  default:
    image = '';
}
$('.BackI').css({
  'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'
}).text(str1[1]);
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoGNYr

Thank you.

Comment: I take it you're just running the code in the browser? If so, I think the //code.jquery.com etc. will try to use the file protocol instead of http/s

Comment: Are you just opening the file locally, or running it on a local webserver? if you're just opening the file it might be trying to load jquery using a file:// URL (try explicitly setting http in this case).

Comment: Yes I'm running the downloaded files locally with browser. No webserver.  I just double click the index.html after unzipping. I've tried adding the "http" to http//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js and http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js . When Chrome opens it does take a bit longer to display the DIV text.

Comment: It works now, sorry did not see that post. Thanks everyone!.